# Python Glob.glob: a wildcard for the number of directories between the root and the destination

Tags: python, path, wildcard, glob

Okay I'm having trouble not only with the problem itself but even with trying to explain my question. I have a directory tree consisting of about 7 iterations, so: `rootdir/a/b/c/d/e/f/destinationdir`

The thing is some may have 5 subdirectory levels and some may have as many as ten, such as:

```
rootdir/a/b/c/d/destinationdir
```

or:

`rootdir/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/destinationdir`

The only thing they have in common is that the destination directory is always named the same thing. The way I'm using the glob function is as follows:

`for path in glob.glob('/rootdir/*/*/*/*/*/*/destinationdir'):

    --- os.system('cd {0}; do whatever'.format(path))`

However, this only works for the directories with that precise number of intermediate subdirectories. Is there any way for me not to have to specify that number of `subdirectories(asterices)`; in other words having the function arrive at the destinationdir no matter what the number of intermediate subdirectories is, and allowing me to iterate through them. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this could be done more easily with `os.walk`:

```
def find_files(root,filename):
    for directory,subdirs,files in os.walk(root):
        if filename in files:
            yield os.join(root,directory,filename)
```

Of course, this doesn't allow you to have a glob expression in the filename portion, but you could check that stuff using regex or fnmatch.

**EDIT**

Or to find a directory:

```
def find_files(root,d):
    for directory,subdirs,files in os.walk(root):
        if d in subdirs:
            yield os.join(root,directory,d)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a pattern for each level of indentation (increase `10` if needed):

```
for i in xrange(10):
    pattern = '/rootdir/' + ('*/' * i) + 'destinationdir'
    for path in glob.glob(pattern):
        os.system('cd {0}; do whatever'.format(path))
```

This will iterate over:

```
'/rootdir/destinationdir'
'/rootdir/*/destinationdir'
'/rootdir/*/*/destinationdir'
'/rootdir/*/*/*/destinationdir'
'/rootdir/*/*/*/*/destinationdir'
'/rootdir/*/*/*/*/*/destinationdir'
'/rootdir/*/*/*/*/*/*/destinationdir'
'/rootdir/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/destinationdir'
'/rootdir/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/destinationdir'
'/rootdir/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/destinationdir'
```

If you have to iterate over directories with arbitrary depth then I suggest dividing the algorithm in two steps: one phase where you investigate where all 'destinationdir' directories are located and a second phase where you perform your operations.

Comment: I like this answer best because you actually use glob and it is simple.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3 [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) now accepts double wildcards to designate any number of intermediate directories, as long as you also pass `recursive=True`:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('**/*.txt', recursive=True)
['1.txt', 'foo/2.txt', 'foo/bar/3.txt', 'foo/bar/baz/4.txt']
```

Comment: but be aware that the '**' glob pattern does not follow symlinks as it could end up in endless loops.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for files, you can use the [Formic package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/formic) (disclosure: I wrote it) - this implements Apache Ant's FileSet Globs with the '**' wildcard:

```
import formic
fileset = formic.FileSet(include="rootdir/**/destinationdir/*")

for file_name in fileset:
    # Do something with file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks much easier to accomplish with a more versatile tool, like the `find` command (your `os.system` call indicates you're on a unix-like system, so this will work).

```
os.system('find /rootdir -mindepth 5 -maxdepth 10 -type d -name destinationdir | while read d; do ( cd $d && do whatever; ); done')
```

..Note that if you are going to put any user-supplied string into that command, this becomes drastically unsafe, and you should use subprocess.Popen instead, executing the shell and splitting the arguments yourself. It's safe as shown, though.