# Getting glob to follow symlinks in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, symlink

Suppose I have a subdirectory of symlinks that looks like the following:

```
subdir/
    folder/
        readme.txt
    symlink/ => ../hidden/
hidden/
    readme.txt
```

If I run the following code:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> list(Path('./subdir/').glob('**/readme.txt'))
```

I would expect the outcome to be:

```
subdir/folder/readme.txt
subdir/symlink/readme.txt
```

But the actual result is:

```
subdir/folder/readme.txt
```

I found out that this is because (for some undocumented reason) the ** operator doesn't follow symlinks.

Is there a way to change this configuration pragmatically?

Comment: That's strange, since there's an [open issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue29475) asking for `glob` to optionally *not* follow symlinks.

Comment: This behavior seems to have been caused as a side effect of fixing this issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue26012. The method `_iterate_directories()` in class `_RecursiveWildcardSelector` of pathlib.py explicitly ignores symlinks.

Comment: Probably of interest: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/77609#issuecomment-1567306837

Answer (score 18):

`pathlib.glob` also doesn't work for me with `**` and symlinks. I've found related issue https://bugs.python.org/issue33428.

As an alternative for Python3 you could use `glob.glob` with `**` and `recursive=True` option (see details https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

```
In [67]: from glob import glob
In [71]: list(glob("./**/readme.txt", recursive=True))
Out[71]:
['./hidden/readme.txt',
 './subdir/folder/readme.txt',
 './subdir/symlink/readme.txt']

In [73]: list(glob("./**/readme.txt", recursive=False))
Out[73]: ['./hidden/readme.txt']
```

Compare to:

```
In [72]: list(Path('.').glob('**/readme.txt'))
Out[72]: [PosixPath('hidden/readme.txt'), PosixPath('subdir/folder/readme.txt')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used `pathlib` before, so you may extend this solution to take advantage of some of its features, but I got this to work using `glob` only.

```
from glob import glob
list(glob('./subdir/*/readme.txt'))
```

Output:

```
['./subdir/folder/readme.txt', './subdir/symlink/readme.txt']
```

If you're set on using `glob` with more than one depth of subdirectory, the hackish solution is to include variations with extra `*/` (e.g. `./subdir/*/*/*/readme.txt`) up to some arbitrary depth, and concatenate the results from each variation.

The more appropriate way to do what you want would be to write a custom function that has the behavior you want (searches through symlinks to arbitrary depth), and handles the case of circular paths in the way you want. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458788/python-glob-glob-a-wildcard-for-the-number-of-directories-between-the-root-and) for tips on doing this with `os.walk` (remember to set `followlinks=True`).

Comment: `Path.glob` and `glob` use the same functionality - the issue I have found is that glob doesn't like following symlinks when using `**`.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `*` instead of `**`, since your directory structure has a specific depth? Interesting to note that [`glob` in javascript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) has the same behavior for `**`.

Comment: I am guessing the reason for this behavior is to avoid issues with infinite depth in the case of symlinks that create directory loops.

Comment: I'm trying to write a solution abstract enough that it can be used in a few case scenarios. There will be instances where the readme.txt file may be burried deep

Comment: Updated solution to reflect your need for deeper paths.

Answer (score 1):

python 3.6 works for me with a call to `rglob`,

```py
import pathspec

p = pathspec.Path("./subdir").rglob("readme.txt")
```